# YouTube Custom URL not working

Tags: url, youtube

my YouTube channel 'MusicCityGaming' has around 2.4 thousand subscribers, and our channel has been around for about 6 months now. We have custom channel art as well, so we definately meet the eligibility requirements for getting a custom URL for my channel.

Obviously, we have had over 500 subscribers (the minimum amount to be eligible for a custom URL) for over 3-4 months now.... I was told by YouTube that I would get a notification in my channel dashboard or an email telling me that I am now eligible for a custom URL.... I have waited for several months now with no notification or email. Since YouTube doesn't have a support line, I can't contact them. Why am I not getting this notification? My subscribers are all complaining because of the long and obnoxious link.

Answer (score -1):

I see that the MusicCityGaming does appear to meet all the requirements, including having a channel icon (which you did not mention in your original question, so I checked). Having said that, you should find your "Get a new custom URL" notification on your https://www.youtube.com/signin?action_prompt_identity=true&next=%2Fdashboard

NOTE: if you have more than one YouTube identity, as in a personal account in addition to a business account, be sure you using the latter.

If that does not work, try the alternative method for qualifying for a custom URL by [linking and verifying](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4569085?rd=1) **MusicCityGaming.com** with either your **Google+** page or your **YouTube channel** page.

Hope that helps. If so, please mark your question as answered.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'd like to ask -- I'm fairly sure I have custom channel art, are you sure I don't have any? Here is the channel - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXoRbxf1q3__kccASRABKA

Comment: Jack, you misunderstood my answer. Yes, I saw your custom channel art. I said that your channel DOES meet all the requirements.

Comment: Do you have both a Business YouTube account AND a Personal YouTube account? If so, then you need to access (i.e. login to) YouTube with your Business account, NOT your "Jack H" personal account.

Jack, if I provided helpful info, please mark my answer as ACCEPTED.